# Change the Bitmapimage color

Tags: c#, wpf

I have gray images in the program resources, I need to change their color to the one I need. How can I do this?

In WinForms, I had a special method for changing the Bitmap color, but it doesn't work with BitmapImage.

Comment: A possible solution depends on the exact structure of your bitmaps. Do they contain grayscale pixels on white background? What is their PixelFormat? How should the different gray values map to a color?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.